# ADT: Avoid duplicating code in package with dependency on another deployed package?

Tags: android, android-intent, adt

When I have e.g. a custom service and a custom activity in the same ADT project, then I can use this in the service, to start my activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyCustomActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

However when I have the service and activity in separate projects, then I cannot do this since I do not have a direct reference to `MyCustomActivity.class`. This is problematic: I do not wish to include a JAR just to be able to fix that broken reference, since I assume this will increase the package size and create redundant data on the device (i.e. activity code is duplicated between the service and activity packages). So instead, I use this (perhaps there are other options?):

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.mypackage.myStringActionName");
startActivity(i); //is this a broadcast?
```

OR

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.mypackage.myStringActionName");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

...But I don't really like sending broadcasts when all I want is to direct the intent to a single activity to tell it to start.

So, what other ways are there to go about avoiding duplication (in ADT)? Or else a better way to send direct intents?

Comment: "Or else a better way to send direct intents?" -- the way you are doing it, using an action string, *is* the "better way".

Comment: @CommonsWare I disagree, since the system has to select which classes receive the intent. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Do not make App A depend upon App B's classes, as then App A breaks once you refactor App B such that the classes differ. The custom action string gives you a stable name by which to identify a component in App B regardless of the actual class that implements that component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, classname));
startActivity(i);
```

the className must contains the packageName and main activity name

Comment: Hi... I don't see such a method for `Intent` in the documentation. I'm on API level 17. There is only `setComponent(ComponentName componentName)`.

Comment: @NickWiggill I am sorry, I have remembered incorrectly
, you are right

Comment: Accepted your answer as it may help someone else.